# Laravel pretty URLs and routing not working on LAMP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created web app with Laravel, which I tested on laravel server ( `php artisan serve` ) and now I want to put it on LAMP so I can test it further, but something is wrong.

When I visit `localhost/public/` I get my home page but when I click on any link inside my app I get `Not found` error. On the other side, when I manually input `localhost/public/index.php/someURL` then I get the linked page.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

This is my `.htaccess` file inside `public` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This is the content of apache2 conf file ( `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` ) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I enabled mod_rewrite with this command: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

UPDATE:

App is placed inside `/var/www/html/`

Comment: Is that the original htaccess bundled with Laravel or some home brew version ? If it's the latter, consider trying with the default one.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Default htaccess fixed only part of the problem. Now named routes works, but if I manually create link to '/about' then I get Not found error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed it. I created another .htaccess file and placed it in root directory /www/html/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Information taken from here: http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Answer (score 6):

Go to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and make sure it looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  Allowoverride All
  Require All Granted   
</Directory>
```

You can locate it right after

```
<Directory /usr/share> 
.... 
</Directory>
```

Perform mod_rewrite and restart apache and it should work!

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. I managed to "fix" it by setting DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public but this is not what I want because I want to give this application to a client and client is not developer so he/she don't know how to setup apache configuration

Comment: It can also be `<Directory /var/www>` in some `apache2.conf` files.